# Can't create view

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I want to create a view like

```
CREATE VIEW monitors_info AS
      SELECT monitors_id, nom
       FROM monitors;
```

But, I got this message

```
 ERROR: No schema has been selected to create in. (using psql)
```

I don't know what I miss, please help me.

Comment: I guess your `search_path` does not point to any existing schema.  Also, please use the formatting options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question;

> ERROR: No schema has been selected to create in. (using psql)

You need to specify the schema. Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW MYSCHEMA.monitors_info AS SELECT MYSCHEMA.monitors_id, MYSCHEMA.nom FROM MYSCHEMA.monitors;
```